# PyCharm 2023.1 unusable with code on network drives (previous versions were OK); any fixes?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

### The issue

I run PyCharm Professional 2023.1 on Windows with miniconda.

I need to write a combination of small(ish) scripts and notebooks, and **I'd ideally need the code to be on a network drive**. In some cases I'll use a local git repository for version control, in other cases the scripts are so banal that's not even necessary. This banal task, which worked very well with previous versions, is de facto impossible with PyCharm 2023.1 because **it becomes so slow it's unusable**. E.g.:

- if I create an empty project, before even adding any new files on it,
  PyCharm behaves like a software from the '80s: I click on a menu and
  I have to wait 5-6 seconds before anything happens.
- I fire up a new
  Jupyter notebook and, after waiting for the notebook to start, even
  running a banal cell like "5+5" can take.. 12 seconds!

My questions are: **does this happen to other people, too? Have you found better solutions than those I have found below?**

### My (partial) solutions

1. Use Spyder for small scripts and notebooks. Where the extra functionalities of PyCharm come in handy:
2. Create a local project on the C drive, then set up the deployment options so as to sync files with the remote drive. This means you can no longer use relative references to import data on the network drives. If you remove the exclusion for ".git" from the deployment options, PyCharm's deployment tool will sync a local git repository to the network drive, too.
3. Create a git repository on the network drive, and use PyCharm to clone from that repository.
4. if you have access to some kind of centralised git repository or equivalent, you can obviously sync between repository - local drive - network drive, but this may add a level of unnecessary complication if the scripts are very small and banal

### Why I think it's a bug

I am well aware that large projects should not be stored on network drives (see *Why I need it* farther down) but this is not that.

I understand that scanning a large code base on a network drive is inefficient, and I understand that IDEs like Spyder are less sophisticated, do less background scanning and will therefore work better with network drives.

But **taking 12 seconds to run a notebook cell with "5+5" is laughable, there is no justification, there is something very wrong going on in the background**.

Not to mention that previous versions of PyCharm worked perfectly well - on the very same network drives, so something must have changed with the updates.

### How I have tried to debug it

I reached the conclusion the issue is having the files on the network drive, because

- I created a new conda environment with just python and spyder
- The new environment gives me the same issues if I create a project on a network drive
- If instead I create a project on the local C drive, both environments work perfectly well

I have also:

- disabled *synchronize external changes* in settings -> system settings
- turned power save mode on

### Why I need it

I am well aware that large projects should be stored on git repositories etc. But here we are not talking about production-critical application. The use case is something like this:

- the work network drive has folders by clients and projects
- as part of the work on a specific project for a specific client, we receive some data from the client. We need to perform some light exploratory analyses on that data, and it is useful to have the scripts and the output in a subfolder of the project, all together.

Comment: Please report issue on YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) attaching logs folder zipped ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue for investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question as an FYI in the hope this can be useful to other people, too.
I have verified that the network drive which was causing issues was, in fact, often slow for a number of external reasons - too many users accessing the drive (even if not that specific folder, etc). I have verified this with a few tests, including transferring files from there to the C drive.

I still do not understand why Spyder was working perfectly fine and why PyCharm was not, but I guess the takeaway is: **slow network drives may work fine with other editors but bring PyCharm to a halt, even when performing operations which should have little to do with the drive itself**, like running "5+5" in a notebook, or clicking a menu (and waiting 10 seconds fr something to happen) while working on a still empty script.

In summary:

1. If you really need to save your scripts on a network drive, ensure that the network drive is fast enough
2. If at all feasible, try a faster drive - the issue is a function of network drive access and does not happen with all network drive
3. If it's not, consider another editor, like Spyder, which is not as affected as PyCharm by this